# How to instruct longest palindrome from a list of numbers?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, palindrome

I am trying to solve a question which says that we need to write a function in which given a list of numbers, we need to find the longest palindrome that we can from given only the numbers in the list.

For eg:

If the given list is : [3,47,6,6,5,6,15,22,1,6,15]

The longest palindrome that we can return is one of length 9, such as [6,15,6,3,47,3,6,15,6].

Additionally, we have the following constraints:

One can only use an array queue, array stack, and a chaining hashmap, and the list we are supposed to return, and the function must run in linear time. And we can use only constant additional space.

My approach was the following:

Since a palindrome can be formed if have an even number of certain characters, we can iterate over all the elements in the list, and store in a chaining hash map, the number of times each number appears in the list. This should take O(N) time since each lookup in the chaining hash map takes constant time, and iterating over the list takes linear time.

Then we can iterate over all the numbers in the chaining hash map, to see which numbers appear an even number of times, and accordingly, just make a palindrome. In the worst case, this will take a O(n) linear time.

Now there are two things I am wondering:

1. How should I make the actual palindrome? Like how do I use the data structures that I am being allowed to use in order to make a palindrome? I am thinking that since the queue is a LIFO data structure, for each number that occurs an even number of times, we add it once to the queue and once to the stack, and so on and so forth. And finally, we can just dequeue everything from the queue, and pop once from the stack, and then add it to the list!
2. It seems that with my approach, it is taking me two linear runs to solve the question. I am wondering if there is a faster way to do this.

Any and all help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get a better algorithm than one that is *O(n)*, as every number in the input has to be inspected, as it might provide a possibility for a longer palindrome. If indeed the output must be a longest palindrome itself (and not only its length), then producing that output itself represents *O(n)*.

You have also omitted one additional thing you have to do in your algorithm: there can be one value in the final palindrome that occurs only once (in the centre). So whenever you encounter a value that occurs an odd number of times, you may reserve one occurrence of that value for putting in the middle of an odd-length palindrome. The even remainder of the occurrences can be used as usual.

As to your questions:

> How should I make the actual palindrome?

There are many ways to do it. But don't forget that if you have an even number of occurrences, you should use *all* those occurrences, not just two. So add half of them to the queue and half of them to the stack. When the frequency is odd, then still do the same (rounded down), and log the number also as a potential centre value.

When you have done this for all values, then dump the queue and stack together in the result list as you suggested, but don't forget to put the centre value in between the two, if you identified such a centre value (i.e. when not all occurrences were even).

> It seems that with my approach, it is taking me two linear runs to solve the question.

You cannot do this better than with a linear time complexity. You can save a bit of time if you use the stack also for the result, and just dump the queue unto the stack (after potentially pushing the centre value).

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution when its palindrome only for the number and not the digit.
for the input: [51,15]
we will return [15] || [51] and not [51,15] =>(5,1,1,5);
feature more your example as a problem 3 doesn't appear twice(and appears in the answer)
or maybe I didn't understand the question.

```
public static int[] polidrom(int [] numbers){
        HashMap<Integer/*the numbere*/,Integer/*how many time appeared*/> hash = new HashMap<>();
        boolean middleFree= false;
        int middleNumber = 0;
        int space = 0;
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        for (Integer num:numbers) {//count how mant times each digit appears
            if(hash.containsKey(num)){hash.replace(num,1+hash.get(num));}
            else{hash.put(num,1);}
        }
        for (Integer num:hash.keySet()) {//how many times i can use pairs
            int original =hash.get(num);
            int insert = (int)Math.floor(hash.get(num)/2);
            if(hash.get(num) % 2 !=0){middleNumber = num;middleFree = true;}//as no copy
            hash.replace(num,insert);
            if(insert != 0){
                for(int i =0; i < original;i++){
                    stack.push(num);
                }
            }
        }

        space = stack.size();
        if(space == numbers.length){ space--;};//all the numbers are been used
        int [] answer = new int[space+1];//the middle dont have to have an pair
        int startPointer =0 , endPointer= space;
        while (!stack.isEmpty()){
            int num = stack.pop();
            answer[startPointer] = num;
            answer[endPointer] = num;
            startPointer++;
            endPointer--;
        }
        if (middleFree){answer[answer.length/2] = middleNumber;}
        return answer;
    }
```

space O(n) => {stack , hashMap , answer Array};
complexity: O(n)
You can skip the part where I used the stack and build the answer array in the same loop.
and I can't think of a way where you will not iterate at least twice;
Hope I've helped

Comment: this code is actually O(N^2); suppose array is 2001 elements, out of which 1000 numbers is 1, 1000 numbers is 2 and 1 number is 3.

in this case ::  for(int i =0; i < original;i++){ .. will take O(N) time to finish. so overall time complexity would be O(N^2)

Comment: Let's analyze it, 
 let's say we have k distinct keys and each one as m instances so n= k*m.
in the first loop, we run on the keys witch are distinct meaning we run K times, in the second loop we run on the instances of the keys so m. because there are nested the complexity is O(m*k) meaning O(n).

Comment: i appreciating your comment, sorry for my bad thinking. cheers : )